# Getting ADMN0022E using the WebSphere 8 Jython admin API

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8

We are using Jython scripts to configure WebSphere applications on our different stages (test, integration, qs, productive). On some servers I get the following exception for some calls:

```
com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException:    com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException javax.management.JMRuntimeException:
    >> SERVER (id=......., host=........) TRACE START:
    >>    javax.management.JMRuntimeException: ADMN0022E: Access is denied for the addNotificationListener operation on AdminService MBean because of insufficient or empty credentials.
    >>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.preInvoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:2671)
    >>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1312)
    >>       at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    >>       at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    >>       at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:346)
    >>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    >>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:86)
    >>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    >>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    >>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:830)
    >>       at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:751)
    >>       at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:158)
    >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:678)
    >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:525)
    >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:616)
    >>       at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1581)
    >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3160)
    >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3030)
    >>       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
    >>       at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    >>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
    >> SERVER (id=......., host=........) TRACE END.
```

The simplest Jython code that gets this error is:

```
try:

    AdminApp.edit('MY_Appl', '[ -MapEnvEntryForEJBMod [[ my.jar my.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml MyServiceBean envName String "" envValue ]]]' )

    AdminConfig.save()
    print "Configure done successfully"
except ScriptingException:
    print "Error:\n"+str(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

I call the script like this:

```
/some_path/WAS/WebSphere_80/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -user user -passwword password -f setejbenv.py
```

The strange thing is that only some calls fail in this way. Other calls, like setting policy sets and bindings for web service clients work without problems.

We are using WebSphere 8.0.0.9.

Does anyone have an idea what credentials are missing, and where to set them?

Comment: Have you tried to (briefly) set the users permission to all permissions to see if you get any change in behaviour? Also I assume your example running the script with the parameter `-passwword`is just a typo in this question as you have a `w` too much.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian No, I haven't tried that yet, mainly since I have to go through some bureaucratic channels to get that (maybe) done. I'm currently looking at a different possible solution (The websphere on a server w/o the problem uses a custom user registry, while this one uses plain LDAP). But I might try that.